# I have a running miktex 2.9 in windows vista, but i can't run chronosys package

Tags: miktex, chronosys

I installed the chronosys package with Miktex Package Manager, but it crashes with the following at the end of the log file:

```
...
! I can't find file `chronosyschr.tex'.
l.32 \input chronosyschr.tex

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
l.32 \input chronosyschr.tex

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

Comment: The miktex package is faulty. You can get the missing files from CTAN http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chronosys. Make a bug report at the miktex bug tracker.

Comment: ok, and now where do i install the files downloaded

Comment: simplest way is just put it in the same folder as your document

Comment: @Pillqu +1 for directing my attention to this package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is due to a bug in MikTeX.